# Making a triangle shape using XML definitions?

Tags: android, xml

Is there a way that I can specify a triangle shape in an XML file?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="triangle">
  <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFF" />
  <solid android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

Can we do this with a path shape or something? I just need an equilateral triangle.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to have worked for the guy who wrote the guidance (and a few commenters): [Android: Draw Equilateral Triangle Shapes In Canvas](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2012/07/08/android-draw-equilateral-triangle-shapes-in-canvas/)

Answer (score 171):

In [this post](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/) I describe how to do it. And here is the XML defining triangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/your_color_here" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Refer to my post if something is unclear or you need explanation how it is built. It is rotated an cutout rectangle :) it is very smart and well working solution.

EDIT: 
to create an arrow pointing like --> use:

```
...
android:fromDegrees="45"
android:toDegrees="45"
android:pivotX="13%"
android:pivotY="-40%" >
...
```

And to create an arrow pointing like <-- use:

```
android:fromDegrees="45"
android:toDegrees="45"
android:pivotX="87%"
android:pivotY="140%" >
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. but an equilateral triangle can never be a right angle triangle.

Comment: @JacekMilewski -- thanks a lot! Care to share what your pivotX/pivotY parameters are for a down arrow? Left? Right?

Comment: To rotate it i change the rotation in layout xml file, not in the triangle definition itself.

Comment: -1 This way you cannot get eqilateral triangle. And anyway, it is having lot's of potential problems ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805826/custom-arrows-without-image-android

Comment: it builds isosceles triangle

Comment: i need one whoch points to the bottom =) how do you calculate the pivot points?

Comment: Is overdraw an issue with this solution? Avoid overdraw at all costs, its the number one reason for sluggish apps.

Comment: I need help to get this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094070/how-to-create-parallogram-background

Comment: I get a random shape, it looks like a square rotated about 35 degrees and with one of the corners cut off. :/

Comment: -1 . This isn't good. The actual dimensions of the view is larger then what appears on screen. It should have wrapped the bounds.

Comment: Can you please share how you derived your values for fromDegrees, toDegrees, pivotX, and pivotY? I have a use case where it is not possible to change the rotation in the layout file.

Comment: I think using a vector or a View as the later answers suggest is better. This solution is a workaround that is not needed.

Answer (score 85):

```
<TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="▼"/>
```

You can get [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=triangle) more options.

Comment: this a good solution. Its easy and clean and you don't need to touch on drawables. Also you just change the color of triangle by using the parameter textColor.

Comment: How do you put that value in xml?

Comment: Copy this TextView and paste it to your xml

Comment: @user531069 : put this on your strings.xml : `<string name="bottom_arrow">&#9660;</string>`

Comment: I want different arrow from the link, I copy and paste &#129032; as text, it shows some unknown character. ?

Comment: This solution creates a new problem of handling Font Padding inside the Text View.

Comment: drawable right click -> add -> Vector image asset -> chose 'arrow drop down' icon.

Comment: Very helpful thanks.  I would also add that you can control the size of the triangle by specifying the text size to use.  For example: `theLabel.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Holo_Small);`

Answer (score 74):

You can use `vector` to make triangle like this

**ic_triangle_right.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0,12l0,12 11.5,-5.7c6.3,-3.2 11.5,-6 11.5,-6.3 0,-0.3 -5.2,-3.1 -11.5,-6.3l-11.5,-5.7 0,12z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

Then use it like

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_triangle_right"
    />
```

For change the color and direction, use `android:tint` and `android:rotation`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_triangle_right"
    android:rotation="180" // change direction
    android:tint="#00f" // change color
    />
```

Result

[image]

For change the shape of vector, you can change the width/height of vector.   Example change width to 10dp

```
<vector 
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        >
       ...
</vector>
```

[image]

Comment: how can I increase and decrease the size of these triangles? By specifying height and width, it doesn't work

Answer (score 56):

You can use [vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html).

If your minimum API is lower than 21, Android Studio automatically creates PNG bitmaps for those lower versions at build time (see [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)). If you use the support library, Android even manages "real vectors" down to API 7 (more on that in the update of this post at the bottom).

A red upwards pointing triangle would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100" >
    <group
        android:name="triableGroup">
        <path
            android:name="triangle"
            android:fillColor="#FF0000"
            android:pathData="m 50,0 l 50,100 -100,0 z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Add it to your layout and remember to set clipChildren="false" if you rotate the triangle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Change the size (width/height) of the triangle by setting the Views layout_width/layout_height attributes. This way you can also get an eqilateral triagle if you do the math correct.

**UPDATE 25.11.2017**

**If you use the support library you can use real vectors (instead if bitmap creation) as far back as API 7**. Simply add:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

do your `defaultConfig` in your module's build.gradle.

Then set the (vector xml) drawable like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/triangle" />
```

Everything is documented very nicely on the [Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) page.

Ever since this feature I've been working entirely without bitmaps in terms of icons. **This also reduces APK size quite a bit.**

Comment: post a link and someone will upload it for you :-)

Comment: +1 `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` has the extra benefit that you can use colors defined in `colors.xml`, because bitmaps are created during build (when the defined colors are not available).

Answer (score 42):

The [solution of Jacek Milewski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421795/1392653) works for me and, based on his solution, if you need and inversed triangle you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="135%" 
            android:pivotY="15%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">    
                <solid android:color="@color/aquamarine" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: -1 This way you cannot get eqilateral triangle. And anyway, it is having lot's of potential problems ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805826/custom-arrows-without-image-android

Answer (score 40):

I would definetely go for implementing a View in this case:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class TriangleShapeView extends View {

    public TriangleShapeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TriangleShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public TriangleShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int w = getWidth() / 2;

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo( w, 0);
        path.lineTo( 2 * w , 0);
        path.lineTo( 2 * w , w);
        path.lineTo( w , 0);
        path.close();

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor( Color.RED );

        canvas.drawPath(path, p);
    }
}
```

Make use of it in your layouts as follows:

```
<TriangleShapeView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff487fff">
</TriangleShapeView>
```

Using this implementation will give you the following result:

[image]

Comment: <com.your.path.to.view.TriangleShapeView ... />

Comment: that is great. how can i change the triangle color. say the initial color is gray but changes to red upon onTouch or onClick?

Comment: This is way better than the hack in xml

Comment: @Peter Hi. can you help me with small improvement?
I need upper right corner to be rounded. how can i achive this?

Comment: How would I add text inside of the triangle?

Comment: i know this solution would work because i have worked with CustomViews before but somehow i am not gettting the red triangle @Peter

Comment: Works fine. But TRANSPARENT color is not painted instead of RED

Answer (score 27):

Using vector drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:width="24dp"
   android:height="24dp"
   android:viewportWidth="24.0"
   android:viewportHeight="24.0">
   <path
        android:pathData="M0,0 L24,0 L0,24 z"
        android:strokeColor="@color/color"
        android:fillColor="@color/color"/>
</vector>
```

[image]

Comment: Using `L` and `z` at the end fixed my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 24):

See answer here:
[Custom arrows without image: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805826/custom-arrows-without-image-android/37254859#37254859)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="32dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="32.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path android:fillColor="#e4e4e8"
          android:pathData="M0 0 h32 l-16 24 Z"/>
</vector>
```

[image: arrow]

Answer (score 13):

May I help you **without** using XML ?

---

Simply,

Custom Layout ( Slice ) :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class Slice extends View {

    Paint mPaint;

    Path mPath;

    public enum Direction {
        NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST
    }

    public Slice(Context context) {
        super(context);
        create();
    }

    public Slice(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        create();
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void create() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mPath = calculate(Direction.SOUTH);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private Path calculate(Direction direction) {
        Point p1 = new Point();
        p1.x = 0;
        p1.y = 0;

        Point p2 = null, p3 = null;

        int width = getWidth();

        if (direction == Direction.NORTH) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + (width / 2), p1.y - width);
        } else if (direction == Direction.SOUTH) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + (width / 2), p1.y + width);
        } else if (direction == Direction.EAST) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x, p1.y + width);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x - width, p1.y + (width / 2));
        } else if (direction == Direction.WEST) {
            p2 = new Point(p1.x, p1.y + width);
            p3 = new Point(p1.x + width, p1.y + (width / 2));
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        path.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);

        return path;
    }
}
```

Your Activity ( Example ) :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Layout extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Slice mySlice = new Slice(getApplicationContext());
        mySlice.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(mySlice, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    }
}
```

Working Example :

[image]

---

Another absolutely simple `Calculate` function you may interested in ..

```
private Path Calculate(Point A, Point B, Point C) {
    Path Pencil = new Path();
    Pencil.moveTo(A.x, A.y);
    Pencil.lineTo(B.x, B.y);
    Pencil.lineTo(C.x, C.y);
    return Pencil;
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, you may. And thank you. There are other people besides OP which are looking for solution who are not asking specifically for XML - as am I.

Comment: onDraw will not be called on classes that derive from ViewGroup, not be default. You have to either enable drawing by setWillNotDraw(false) or inherit from a View instead.

Answer (score 10):

You can add following triangle in background using following xml

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100" >
    <group
        android:name="triableGroup">
        <path
            android:name="triangle"
            android:fillColor="#848af8"
            android:pathData="M 0,20 L 0,0 L 100,0 L 100,20 L 54,55  l -1,0.6  l -1,0.4  l -1,0.2  l -1,0   l -1,-0  l -1,-0.2  l -1,-0.4  l -1,-0.6    L 46,55   L 0,20 -100,-100 Z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

The whole logic to customize xml design is in `pathData`. Consider top-left as (0,0) and design the layout as per your requirement. 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138513/4788260) answer.

Answer (score 7):

For those who want a right triangle arrow, here you go:

**STEP 1:** Create a drawable XML file, copy and paste the following XML content into your drawable XML. (Please be informed that you can use any name for your drawable XML file. For my case, I name it "v_right_arrow")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="15%"
            android:pivotY="-36%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"  >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="1dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="#000000"  />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**STEP 2:** In your layout's XML, create a View and bind its background to the drawable XML that you have just created in **STEP 1**. For my case, I bind v_right_arrow to my View's background property.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/v_right_arrow">
</View>
```

Sample output:

[image]

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="0dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="#fff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:pivotX="135%"
                android:pivotY="1%"
                android:toDegrees="45">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="-60dp"
                        android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 4):

I try to create triangle image like back button of android navigation bar but I haven't found any solution.

Now, I found the solution with myself and would like to share it.

[image: triangle navigation bar android]

use xml below

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="20dp"
    android:left="480dp"
    android:right="60dp"
    android:top="20dp">
    <shape>
        <size android:width="60dp" />
        <corners android:radius="80dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#AAA" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="480dp"
    android:right="70dp"
    android:top="20dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-28"
        android:pivotX="96%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-20">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="80dp"/>
            <size android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="#AAA" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="20dp"
    android:right="70dp"
    android:top="480dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="28"
        android:pivotX="96%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-20">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="80dp"/>
            <size android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="#AAA" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have never done this, but from what I understand you can use the PathShape class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/PathShape.html

Comment: How to use the path shape in XML?

Comment: This was helpful for finding the right part to use, but doesn't offer nearly enough explanation on how to use it.  Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: Sorry Sebastian and Navarr... I indicated in my answer that I have never used it, so I'm not sure how to go about using it.  This just seems like the class that would get the job done.  I agree though that there isn't enough documentation for it.

Comment: PathShape does not seem to have an associated XML syntax. The XML Shape-tag only supports rectangle, oval, line and ring. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 3):

I my be late to party and I came across same problem and Google pointed me to this StackOverflow thread as first result.

> I tried using xml way to add triangle and find out a problem that the triangle
>   shape via xml approach is taking more space than it appears.

See screen shot with layout bounds on

[image]

So ended up making this custom view class which can draws Triangle of any of following types:-

1. up pointing
2. down pointing
3. left pointing &
4. right pointing

asas

```
package com.hiteshsahu.materialupvotewidget;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class TriangleShapeView extends View {

    private int colorCode = Color.DKGRAY;

    public int getColorCode() {
        return colorCode;
    }

    public void setColorCode(int colorCode) {
        this.colorCode = colorCode;
    }

    public TriangleShapeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (isInEditMode())
            return;
    }

    public TriangleShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (isInEditMode())
            return;
    }

    public TriangleShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        if (isInEditMode())
            return;
    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int w = getWidth() / 2;
        int h = getHeight() / 2;

        //Choose what type of triangle you want here
        Path path = getLeftTriangle(w, h);

        path.close();
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(colorCode);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawPath(path, p);
    }

    @NonNull
    /**
     * Return Path for down facing triangle
     */
    private Path getInvertedTriangle(int w, int h) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(w, 2 * h);
        path.lineTo(2 * w, 0);
        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        return path;
    }

    @NonNull
    /**
     * Return Path for Up facing triangle
     */
    private Path getUpTriangle(int w, int h) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(0, 2 * h);
        path.lineTo(w, 0);
        path.lineTo(2 * w, 2 * h);
        path.lineTo(0, 2 * h);
        return path;
    }

    @NonNull
    /**
     * Return Path for Right pointing triangle
     */
    private Path getRightTriangle(int w, int h) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(2 * w, h);
        path.lineTo(0, 2 * h);
        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        return path;
    }

    @NonNull
    /**
     * Return Path for Left pointing triangle
     */
    private Path getLeftTriangle(int w, int h) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(2 * w, 0);
        path.lineTo(0, h);
        path.lineTo(2 * w, 2 * h);
        path.lineTo(2 * w, 0);
        return path;
    }
}
```

You can Simply use it in xml layout like this

```
 <com.hiteshsahu.materialupvote.TriangleShapeView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"></com.hiteshsahu.materialupvote.TriangleShapeView>
```

**I know OP want solutions in xml solution but as I pointed out problem with xml approach .** I Hope it might help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Using the solution of [Jacek Milewski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421795/2914140) I made an oriented down angle with a transparent background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:pivotX="65%"
            android:pivotY="20%"
            android:toDegrees="135"
            >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/blue"
                    />
                <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can change `android:pivotX` and `android:pivotY` to shift the angle.

Usage:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_angle_down"
    />
```

[image]

Parameters depend on the size of the image. For instance, if `ImageView` has size 100dp*80dp, you should use these constants:

```
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="135"
    android:pivotX="64.5%"
    android:pivotY="19%"
    android:toDegrees="135"
    >
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I provide this customView below if you don't want to hack xml.
Please have a try.

---

```
/**
 * TriangleView
 *
 * @author Veer
 * @date 2020-09-03
 */
class TriangleView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private var triangleColor: Int = 0
    private var direction = Direction.Bottom

    private val paint by lazy {
        Paint().apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            color = triangleColor
        }
    }

    init {
        initStyle(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    }

    private fun initStyle(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int
    ) {
        val ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TriangleView, defStyleAttr, 0)
        with(ta) {
            triangleColor =
                getColor(R.styleable.TriangleView_triangle_background, Color.parseColor("#000000"))

            val directionValue =
                getInt(R.styleable.TriangleView_triangle_direction, Direction.Bottom.value)
            direction = when (directionValue) {
                Direction.Top.value -> Direction.Top
                Direction.Bottom.value -> Direction.Bottom
                Direction.Left.value -> Direction.Left
                Direction.Right.value -> Direction.Right
                else -> Direction.Bottom
            }

            recycle()
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        calculatePath(direction).let {
            canvas.drawPath(it, paint)
        }
    }

    private fun calculatePath(direction: Direction): Path {
        var p1: Point? = null
        var p2: Point? = null
        var p3: Point? = null

        val width = width
        val height = height

        when (direction) {
            Direction.Top -> {
                p1 = Point(0, height)
                p2 = Point(width / 2, 0)
                p3 = Point(width, height)
            }
            Direction.Bottom -> {
                p1 = Point(0, 0)
                p2 = Point(width / 2, height)
                p3 = Point(width, 0)
            }
            Direction.Left -> {
                p1 = Point(width, 0)
                p2 = Point(0, height / 2)
                p3 = Point(width, height)
            }
            Direction.Right -> {
                p1 = Point(0, 0)
                p2 = Point(width, height / 2)
                p3 = Point(0, height)
            }
        }

        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(p1.x.toFloat(), p1.y.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(p2.x.toFloat(), p2.y.toFloat())
        path.lineTo(p3.x.toFloat(), p3.y.toFloat())
        return path
    }

    private enum class Direction(val value: Int) {
        Top(0),
        Bottom(1),
        Left(2),
        Right(3)
    }
}

<declare-styleable name="TriangleView">
    <attr name="triangle_direction" format="enum">
        <enum name="top" value="0" />
        <enum name="bottom" value="1" />
        <enum name="left" value="2" />
        <enum name="right" value="3" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="triangle_background" format="reference|color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_fill_color_shape"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_triangle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-15%"
        android:pivotY="77%"
        android:toDegrees="45" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/black_color" />

            <solid android:color="@color/white" />

            <padding android:left="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item android:top="200dp">
    <shape android:shape="line" >
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/black_color" />

        <solid android:color="@color/white" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: -1 This way you cannot get eqilateral triangle. And anyway, it is having lot's of potential problems ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805826/custom-arrows-without-image-android

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a Equilateral triangle [here](https://material.io/icons/).
Choose VectorDrawable so the size is flexible.
It' integrated into Android Studio as  plugin.

If you have an SVG image, you can use [this](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) to convert it to VectorDrawable too.

Once you have a VectorDrawable, changing its colour and rotation is easy like others have mentioned.