# Draw Custom Shape

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view

How I can draw this type of shape and change color in runtime
 I am referring this [Making a triangle shape using xml definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517589/making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions/18421795#18421795) but its not giving as expecting result [image]

Comment: If it has fixed size, it's possible.

Comment: ya fix size(wrap) but it should work on all size of phone .. @tinysunlight can you give me ?

Comment: Can you show how you use it?

Comment: view with background and inside 2 textview

Answer (score 1):

Use 9 patch image For that.

[9 patch image](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Or Here you can make that shape Direct,

[Draw trapezoid shape](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

Comment: but all elements Colors are not fix and i have to set this for textview background .so in 1st i want to set 1,2,3 text in middle one i want title and in down arrow/tragnle only color so i dont think only image will do

Comment: set it on Background and Use TextView for write the Text.

Comment: its possbile to have xml ? coz in this u cant change color in run time

Comment: how can you give some sinppet

Comment: crop your shape and save it. then go to direct trapezoid shape  link and there select that image and download your shape.

Comment: then i need x amt of image coz color can be anything