# From pathdata content to png

Tags: android, image, mobile, png

Could you tell please how could I convert the pathdata content to png?

The code below is an xml written for Android.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:height="64dp"
 android:width="64dp"
 android:viewportHeight="600"
 android:viewportWidth="600" >
 <group
     android:name="rotationGroup"
     android:pivotX="300.0"
     android:pivotY="300.0"
     android:rotation="45.0" >
     <path
         android:name="v"
         android:fillColor="#000000"
         android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" />
 </group>
```

I need to find some way to convert the information below to its correspondent image.

> M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z

Comment: Can  you please explain more? Because you cannot convert pathData to image. PathData will decide the position of drawable item. If you want to know what does this M and other code stands for you can visit the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677768/how-to-create-androidpathdata)

Comment: hi @androidOnHigh . The purpose of the xml above is to show an image. My doubt is: how to convert the code above in an image to use it in another system? Even now, I don't have the image png. This is my doubt: How to get the png?

Comment: After some hard word, I got it. At first, convert the vectordrawable to svg. Finally, bummm: you can convert the svg to png.