# List of available icons?

Tags: java, android, icons

When I used an Activity Template in Android Studio I got a Navigation View where the following icons were used:

```
<item ... android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" ... />
<item ... android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp" />
<item ... android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp" />
```

I'm not very familiar with Android so **my question** is where I can find a list of all available icons (and if the list differs for different Andriod versions etc).

Comment: You want list of icons in Android sdk or custom icons?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what I'm looking for, but as "standard" as possible. I'm sure there are lots of available icons, I just don't know their names.

Comment: This is standard icons from Google: https://material.io/icons/
And this is custom icons (included standard icons from Google): https://materialdesignicons.com/. You can choose the size, or export list of icons for support multi-dimension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create android:pathData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677768/how-to-create-androidpathdata)

Comment: The answer I was looking for is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677768/how-to-create-androidpathdata

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Select the desired icon [here](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=info&style=baseline). For example, you need **info** icon. 
   Look at what section is the icon. See that, the **info** icon is in the **Action** section.
2. Find XML-file by icon name [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons). Open **Action** folder. XML-files for Android in these folders: **drawable-anydpi-v21**. We need file **ic_info_black_24dp.xml**
3. Copy **ic_info_black_24dp.xml** to you Android studio project to folder app/res/drawable.
4. Use icon

   `<item ... android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp" />`

Comment: It is also useful just to download the whole icons repository to your machine: `git clone git@github.com:google/material-design-icons.git`