# How to create this shape in Android

Tags: android, android-shape

I want create shape such as this image : 
[image]

But i do not want use `9 pach png` image, i want create this shape in drawable folder.
How can i create this? 
Any help could be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You need at least one 9 patch for the triangle. Otherwise, it's 2 rectangles

Comment: @cricket_007, yes it's 2 rectangles, but i do not want use 9 patch image. i want create this with shape

Comment: It may be worth looking at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517589/making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions

Comment: @cricket_007, thank you man, i create this in drawable and with XML. after create this i send code in this topic. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

#### Create your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ul_ts.emvsdktester.drawabletraining.Main7Activity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shape4"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Create my_shape4.xml in your drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">
    <group>
        <path
            android:pathData="M0 20 L50 20 L60 0 L100 0"
            android:strokeColor="#000000"
            android:strokeWidth="4" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#42ce3b"
            android:pathData="M100 0 L100 50 L0 50 L0 20 L50 20 L60 2 L100 2"
            android:strokeWidth="0" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

#### The results

[image]

Comment: can you please explain , how you created my_shape4.xml

Comment: @UmarAta create an example file named my_shape4.xml inside your drawable folder and copy the copy I've posted in the answer. easy !!

Comment: that's not what I asked, I simply  mean to ask that how you coded the vector drawable for this shape is there any tutorial or link for decumentation?

Comment: @UmarAta you can ready more about vectors in [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html)