# How to draw triangle shape in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image: Traingle Image]
How to create shape in android using xml? and can we arrange those triangles as circle?

Comment: this  link maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421795/8164071

Comment: https://github.com/adityasd/ButtonShapes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/rightArrow">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"  >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="#000000"  />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

For the desired direction of triangle you can play with the degrees and pivotx/y points

e.g

```
<rotate
            android:fromDegrees="220"
            android:toDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="35%"
            android:pivotY="5%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="1dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="#000000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
```

will give you 'v' shaped triangle

alternate for rotate
this property also given v shape triangle

```
android:rotation="180"
```