# Button with 2 corners only

Tags: android

I have to create buttons styled like this:

[image]

Yes, strange I know. Those 2 corners should not scale if button text is shorter / longer.

Is this possible to create it using an XML ?

- I tried a vector but the vector scales with the size of button.
- Any other idea I have is to do it programmatically, e.g., something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26574726/7232539)

(Explanation of the design: we're experimenting with the design. Imagine button with 4 such corners. Buttons next to each other each having 2 corners close to the other one, etc. Our users love fancy design ... . :-) )

Comment: you can use a 9-pitch drawable as background

Comment: I am sure that is not what you may real want! I hope if you mention the purpose of all this! We can suggest the best approach! Try to comment if you still want!

Comment: @Xenolion: Updated. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create customView

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Button text.."
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <View
           android:background="#000000"
           android:layout_width="1dp"
           android:layout_height="10dp"/>
        <View
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pMIa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Okay after a little research and best practice you surely need a `Layerlist` as a background for your `Button`(though even a `TextView` will work i.e it is also clickable like any view).

**SOLUTION:**

You will have to open the `drawables` folder and add a drawable resource called lets say `custom_button_background` then use this layerlist inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="20dp" android:bottom="20dp" android:left="20dp" android:right="20dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="80dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="80dp" android:bottom="80dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then we are done! This will be our background, In my Android studio the Preview for this look like this:
[image: image on how it looks]
You can adjust the values to reduce them to your needs. To set this as your `Button` or any `View` you simply add this attribute to it:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_button_background"
```

Just adjust the measures to fit your Button Size!