# Triangle shape like an arrow in list for API < 23

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I have been following the answer for this question [Making a triangle shape using xml definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517589/making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions).

I need to create a triangle that looks like arrow to be placed at the end of selected list item (see attached photos).

[image: ArrowWithTriangle]

I have managed to get it working by do the following:

```
shape_diamond.xml
-----------------

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:color="@color/color_transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/color_gray" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And create a new selector

```
selector_list_item.xml
----------------------

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@color/color_orange" />
            <item android:width="28dp"
                  android:height="28dp"
                  android:right="-14dp"
                  android:gravity="center|right"
                  android:drawable="@drawable/shape_diamond" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@color/color_orange" />
            <item android:width="28dp"
                  android:height="28dp"
                  android:right="-14dp"
                  android:gravity="center|right"
                  android:drawable="@drawable/shape_diamond" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@color/color_orange" />
            <item android:width="28dp"
                  android:height="28dp"
                  android:right="-14dp"
                  android:gravity="center|right"
                  android:drawable="@drawable/shape_diamond" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_transparent" />
</selector>
```

Everything works well for API 23+ because it supports "WIDTH" attribute. But it doesn't work in API below 23.

Does anyone know how to make it work for API that is ***below*** API 23 which does **not** support the "WIDTH" attribute?

Comment: do not use such xml tricks, use 9 patch drawable instead

Comment: Or you can use a custom view that draw what you want to draw.

Comment: @KevinRobatel in that case use a custom `Drawable` (or custom `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape`), not custom `View`

Comment: @pskink, I am new to Android, I am not sure what is 9 patch drawable. I am using xml because I can connect the color to match whatever background color that I used via theme `@color/color_gray`. Well, `@color/color_gray` is just an example as I am using more meaningful name. I am interested on the custom view / custom drawable. Can this custom drawable be used to create the triangle with whatever background color (eg. `@color/color_gray`)? Thank you :)

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch and https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: @pskink I looked into 9patch. It is really COOL!!!! But I still confuse on how to apply on my selector. See, the problem is that with the "Width" attribute which is not supported for API < 23. 9 patch will have the exact problem because it will grow as much as it required. In my solution, I can limit it using `ImageView`, but then I do not know how to show this `ImageView` when the list is selected and hide it when it is not selected.

Comment: something like [that](https://pasteboard.co/H3bK1ZH.png)

Comment: @pskink should I save it as .9.png file?

Comment: yes, it is a nine patch png file

Comment: Hi @pskink, do you put this file in drawable folder? I tried to reference it using `android:drawable="@drawable/test.9.png"` in `selector_list_item.xml`, but it can't compile. It gives me this error `Error:error: resource drawable/test.9.png (aka com.warehouse.waredriver:drawable/test.9.png) not found.` But I don't think it will solve my problem. I need to control the width and height and place this diamond shape to the end of the list.

Comment: remove `.9.png`